Local Wordpress not loading a theme's default page
I installed Wordpress using XAMPP. When I install any theme, it doesn't load the theme's default page. Instead it shows a blank page with some elements on it.
I tried some solutions I saw online, like clearing my browser's cache, but it didn't work.
This problem happened before when I installed the theme Neve. Somehow I managed to activate its default page design by tinkering in the Customize section. But, on a fresh Wordpress installation, no matter what theme I install they don't show their default page.
Can anyone help me with this issue?
This is how it looks on my local

This is how it should look after installing the theme.


On a default WP installation the home page is defaulted to a post, you have to indeed set it in the customization area to a page. I dont see the problem here, since you mention it is a fresh installation, you must expect this behaviour.

In Settings -> Reading, I choose "A static page" and then a blank Home page I created. The website stills looks like in my first picture but now displays the "Home" header.

Still, the content as shown in the image, is most likely demo content that you have to import manualy.

Rule out caching issues:
Check Browser:

Try forcing a complete refresh holding [shift] while clicking the refresh button or using the shortcut keys [ctrl][shift][r].
Try an incognito window or another browser that hasn't previously opened the site.

Check Server (unlikely since PHP is server-side, but easy to try):

Try completely killing/restarting the server process
Try disabling XAMPP caching...
Some googling looks like XAMPP doesn't typically have caching enabled by default, but maybe a specific installation package you used does. Although somewhat dated, see How to disable Apache caching in Apache-XAMPP?, specifically the response by @Siddesh but also note the comment by @kishor10d on the orginal question about disabling PHP's OPcache.

Verify theme fully configured
On my testing site, Neve's initial appearance when installed is also like your first screenshot. It seems that Neve is more of a framework or template manager instead of setting up any actual page templates itself. However, the following steps enabled me to install templates/plugins/pages/menus which then appear similar to the expectation in your second screenshot:

In wp-admin, click Neve > Neve Options in sidebar menu
Click "Go to Starter Sites" button
Click "Install and Activate" to install Cloud Templates & Patterns Collection plugin
In onboarding screen, select "Business"
Select first design which matches your expected screenshot
After installation complete, follow setup wizard (or most steps can be skipped)
Check your front-end

